# Is there a possible way to assign the position of a string to a random integer?

Tags: python

I'm doing some code on a banking system wherein there is a pre-set password, then the program will generate a random number using randint, then that random number is a position of a character in the pre-set password. The user must type the character that is in the position of the number that was generated, for example, if my pre-set password is 12345 and the generated number was 3, I should type 4 to be given access to the system.

As you could see, I'm testing out calling the character from the string and merging it with the random number but it doesn't work, do you have any other ideas to perform it? Thanks. Sorry if it may cause you some confusion but this is how far as my code has gone, I'm still starting out with python though.

```
import random

randomOne = (random.randint(0,3))

password = "code"

print(randomOne)
decode = input("input a character: ")

if decode == password + str(randomOne):
    print("Access Granted")
    pass
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

Comment: _"...and merging it with the random number..."_. Hang on, what random number? I see that you import random, but you never actually call a function from that module.

Comment: This code does not call any random function anywhere. Your variable RandomFive is also never assigned anything.

Comment: `print(RandomFive)` will give error as it is never initialized.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the code when I tried to post it. I'll try another one.

Comment: For some reason, I wouldn't feel secure using a bank that handled passwords in this way. Hopefully this is for a homework problem rather than production code in a financial institution.

Comment: I see. I understand your frustration. Yes, it is school work but I'm quite burned out thinking of ways to do it. Yes I also tried password[0] and so on but it still doesn't work. I'm sorry, but I'm still learning everything as best as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#This is your randomly generated character position in the password
randomIndex = random.randint(0,len(code)-1)

#This is the character itself
randomCharacter = code[randomIndex]

#Ask the user for input
reply = input("Please enter the character in position", randomIndex+1)

#Check to see if user's input matches the actual character
if reply == randomCharacter:
    print("Access")
else:
    print("Fail")
```

Comment: Lol, you made me edit my answer because for a second there I thought I was wrong

Comment: I'm not quite sure sir, I thank you for your contribution. I want to understand the code as much as I can instead of just copying and pasting what you provided and called it a day. I hope you can explain to me how you linked the random numbers to the position of the characters in the string.

Comment: @Boxhead assuming you are familiar with the concept of indexing, your problem requires you to randomly generate an index. In our case, the index must simply be an integer between 0 and the length of the password. The random generator simply randomly generates an integer in between these bounds, which I store into `randomCharacter` and use later. Does this help?

Comment: so basically, that random index there, beside code already links the position of the characters in the string to the randomly generated value?

Comment: No, `randomIndex` is only an integer. `code[randomIndex]` is what grabs the actual character from the string.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thank you so much. Sorry for the trouble but I'm really thankful that you helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any random numbers in here,

If you **must** know the index it chose, use:

```
random_position = random.randint(0, len(password)-1)
random_letter = password[random_number]
#then ask them to enter the letter at the index it chose
```

Otherwise if you only need a random letter from password use:

```
random_letter = random.choice(password)
#then ask for them to enter the letter it chose
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `random.randrange` here would work. This will allow you to build a range using the `len` of your password, and then select a random integer from that range. You can then use this random int to index your code password.

```
from random import randrange

pwd = 'code'
pos = randrange(len(pwd))

attempt = input(f'Enter character at index {pos}: ')

if attempt == pwd[pos]:
    print('Access Granted')
else:
    print('Access Denied')
```

Comment: I found that you're answer is correct sir. Though, I haven't covered randrange in my class yet that's why I need a different approach and I want to understand on how could make the random integer be linked to the characters of the string. But your answer is something that I should read on to. :)

Comment: @Boxhead yep and check out `random.choice` you could use that here a s well https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html